# not found "each" statement, why?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
storePersonas.loadData([],false);
storePersonas.load({params:{'NIPersona':NIPersona}, callback: compruebaExitoPersonas});
p=0;
storePersonas.each(function(rec) {
persona=rec.get('LIT_PERSONA');
console.log(persona+" indice p: "+p);
                            treeNode.getChildAt(v).getChildAt(0).appendChild({
            id: "p"+p,
            text: persona,
            iconCls: 'persona',
            leaf: true
            });
            p=p+1;
});
```

does not enter the "each" statement, I see in the browser chrome and if you have at least one content in "LIT_PERSONA".

greetings and thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens:

You clear the store in a weird way: (I would use `storePersonas.removeAll()` )

```
storePersonas.loadData([],false);
```

You fire an asynchronious request to load data:

```
 storePersonas.load({
    params:{
        'NIPersona':NIPersona
    },
    callback: compruebaExitoPersonas
  });
```

(unless you have instantiated it higher in the code) you create a global variable = 0

```
p=0;
```

You iterate over an empty store (resulting into stepping over it)

```
storePersonas.each(function(rec) {
    persona=rec.get('LIT_PERSONA');
    console.log(persona+" indice p: "+p);

    treeNode.getChildAt(v).getChildAt(0).appendChild({
        id: "p"+p,
        text: persona,
        iconCls: 'persona',
        leaf: true
    });
    p=p+1;
});
```

After a while you got you're assynchronious answer back!

`compruebaExitoPersonas()` is called, your data is in the store now!

**UDPATE**

You can do something like this:

```
var addChildNodes = function(store){
    var node = treeNode.getChildAt(v);

    node.removeAll(); //remove all childNodes before adding them all again (don't want doubles, do you?)

    store.each(function(rec, p) {
        var persona = rec.get('LIT_PERSONA');

        console.log(persona + " indice p: " + p);

        node.getChildAt(0).appendChild({
            id: "p" + p,
            text: persona,
            iconCls: 'persona',
            leaf: true
        });
   });
}
storePersonas.removeAll();
storePersonas.load({
    params:{
        NIPersona: NIPersona
    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success){
        if(success){
            addChildNodes(this); //this refers to the store
            compruebaExitoPersonas.apply(this, arguments); //calling the provided callback with the scope (this) and all the arguments
        } else {
            alert('ajax call failed!');
        }
    }
});
```